# Question marks in \if condition -> "\if?\SAP@examdate?"

Tags: conditionals

I have problem understanding the question marks in the `\if` command `\if?\SAP@examdate?` that I encountered the following statement in the .cls of sapthesis [(CTAN link)](https://ctan.org/pkg/sapthesis):

```latex
\ifSAP@noexaminfo\relax
\else
    \if?\SAP@examdate?
      \ifcase\SAP@examinercount
        \SAP@ThesisNotDefensedLabel%
      \else
        \ClassError{sapthesis}{You have specified one or more examiners but not
        the date of the final exam}{E.g. \protect\examdate{17 July 2015}}
      \fi
    \else
      \ifcase\SAP@examinercount
        %\ClassError{sapthesis}{You have specified the final exam date but no examiner}{E.g. \protect\examiner{Prof. Giulio Cesare}}
        \SAP@ThesisDefensedLabelA\ \SAP@examdate
      \else
        \SAP@ThesisDefensedLabelA\ \SAP@examdate\\
        \SAP@ThesisDefensedLabelB:\\[2mm]
        \the\SAP@examinertoks%
      \fi
    \fi
\fi
```

In the main `\SAP@examdate` is called to set the date for the thesis discussion, like `\examdate{xx/xx/2023}`. Here is its definition:

```latex
\def\SAP@examdate{}
\newcommand{\examdate}[1]{\def\SAP@examdate{#1}}
```

Which is the meaning for the question marks around `\SAP@examdate` ? It seems like a negation but online I didn't found anything on the topic. Thank you for your help.

Comment: unrelated but the code has `%` in all the wrong places it does nothing here `\SAP@ThesisNotDefensedLabel%`  but there should be one here `\if?\SAP@examdate?%`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please extend your code to a MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.

Comment: Why ```\if?\SAP@examdate?``` should have ```%``` at the end?

Comment: For documentation on TeX primitive commands such as `\if` refer to the TeXbook. See also [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?rq=1) ■ For the `%` refer to  [symbols - What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat/7459#7459)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is testing if the macro is empty.

```
\if?\SAP@examdate?
```

If you know `\SAP@examdate` can never start with `?` this is only true if `\SAP@examdate` is empty so the test is `\if??`  and the two `?` tokens are compared